# Python: PD.ExcelWriter does not append data

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to populate DataFrame to existing excel like below:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel, engine="openpyxl", mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet)
```

My DataFrame has around 50k data. Process takes around 30 mins, but not still completed.

Same above code is completing in a minute in another machine. Both machines are actually of same configuration, but not sure why it does not work fine in one of the machines.

Existing excel is a 7mb file and has 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can append the data using Xlwings:

```
excel_app = xw.App(visible=False)
excel_book = excel_app.books.open(path)
excel_sheet = excel_book.sheets[sheetname]

col_A = excel_sheet.range('A1')
start_row = col_A.end('down').row + 1 #This line is to find last row
excel_sheet.range('A'+ str(start_row)).value = df  
excel_sheet.range('' + str(start_row) + ':' + str(start_row)).api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp) #Delete Header from appended excel
excel_book.save()
excel_book.close()
excel_app.quit()
```

`Xlwings` completed process under 30 seconds.